# What does "gsettings get com.ubuntu.update-manager launch-time 1382579402" mean?

Tags: update-manager, gsettings

When I run `gsettings get com.ubuntu.update-manager launch-time` the response is `1382579402`. What does the value of `1382579402` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's presumably a time in Unix epoch format, i.e. seconds since 01/01/1970 UTC. It tells you when update manager last ran (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/netrunner/update-manager/blob/master/data/com.ubuntu.update-manager.gschema.xml.in)).

You can display it in a more user-friendly way with the `date` utility.

```
 $ date --date="@1382579402"
Thu Oct 24 03:50:02 CEST 2013
```

Or perl:

```
 $ perl -e 'print localtime(1382579402)."\n";'
Thu Oct 24 03:50:02 2013
```

To get the current time in that format:

```
 $ date +%s      # note: lowercase "s"
1393760872
```

Comment: So in this context, it is the date and time I **first** ran update manager?

Comment: No, last time it ran (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/netrunner/update-manager/blob/master/data/com.ubuntu.update-manager.gschema.xml.in)).

Comment: Perfect. Maybe you can add that to the answer :) I'll accept it as soon as I'm able to.